# hdd mount point

Tags: debian, mount

I have a SSD drive (sda1 below) which when I mount it mounts at a weird mount point, like `/media/bera/e3039d7d-0d02-4531-b639-610bd8e92095/`

I want it to mount at `/media/bera/ssd1/`

```
sudo blkid
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="44FB-5FD2" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="829a028e-01ab-4aa4-9c6b-cbb73aaec779"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="351e8515-7d2a-459c-b97c-481ec2bdfac4" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="a8e1af45-eac7-4928-a2b1-3ea0a0280fdb"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="735b3ec9-a4fa-4fd6-b41f-838d49603d14" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="c7e1c586-1f10-4207-8423-f3e8220a5bd5"
/dev/sda1: UUID="e3039d7d-0d02-4531-b639-610bd8e92095" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="ssd" PARTUUID="8618f5a0-0f31-4543-bcd2-c38d05be3ce1"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="f1606940-3163-4c20-b25e-6404eff7da0b" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="lagring" PARTUUID="5b18ef95-95fe-450f-a2e0-32fdc653c07a"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="Seagate Backup Plus Drive" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="565A74C75A74A581" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="d14425a5-01"

sudo nano /etc/fstab

# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# systemd generates mount units based on this file, see systemd.mount(5).
# Please run 'systemctl daemon-reload' after making changes here.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=351e8515-7d2a-459c-b97c-481ec2bdfac4 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=44FB-5FD2  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p3 during installation
UUID=735b3ec9-a4fa-4fd6-b41f-838d49603d14 none            swap    sw              0       0
# my attempt
UUID="e3039d7d-0d02-4531-b639-610bd8e92095" /media/bera/ssd1/ ext4 defaults     0       2
```

But when I mount it, the point is `/media/bera/e3039d7d-0d02-4531-b639-610bd8e92095/`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the quotation marks around the `UUID="e3039d7d-0d02-4531-b639-610bd8e92095"` entry in `/etc/fstab`. The line should look like this:

```
UUID=e3039d7d-0d02-4531-b639-610bd8e92095 /media/bera/ssd1 ext4 defaults     0       2
```

Mounting from GUI is done by [UDisks](https://github.com/storaged-project/udisks) which by default mounts the device to `/run/media/<user>/<uuid>` (`/media/<user>/<uuid>` on Debian based distributions). When the device is referred in fstab UDisks will use the mountpoint and mount options from there, but the UUID must not be in quotation marks because internally UDisks simpy compares the part after `UUID=` to the filesystem UUID.

Alternatively you can set the filesystem label to `ssd1` and UDisks will use the label instead of UUID. For ext4 ou can set the label with `e2label <device> ssd1`.

Few notes:

- In this case the `/media/bera/ssd1` folder must exist, UDisks won't create it for you.
- In general the `/media/<user>` folder is meant for temporary mounts. Nothing prevents you from using it, but if you are already using fstab, you can mount the device to a "better" place, perhaps somewhere your home directory (but that's up to you).
- Adding the `nofail` option might be a good idea if this is a removable device -- without it the system will stop at boot if the device is not present.